# Time in mouse velocity tracker

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, milliseconds

Building a function to track the velocity of the mouse what Is the best time we can get?To build a function like this we have to do time/distance and to be more accurate usually in this type of function the date is taken.But what type of date?The time is taken until what point?Milliseconds or more?

Comment: Maybe you can be more clear anout what you want to achieve? Why wouldn't just doing this not be fast enough?

Comment: [Search: 'mouse velocity'](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+mouse+velocity)

Comment: I wanted to say this:When we get date we get what?The time until milliseconds?

Comment: Depending on the hosts you want to run this on, you may be able to use [*Performance.now*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) which returns a time value in microseconds that should be accurate to ±5 microseconds (±0.005 millisecond) but may only be accurate to 1 millisecond (depending on the host).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript on browsers, you have two options:

1. Cross-browser, you can use `Date.now()` (or `new Date().getTime()` on really old ones) which gives you, at best, millisecond precision. The number you get is milliseconds-since-The-Epoch (Jan 1st 1970 at midnight, GMT) as a whole number. On many modern browsers, the resolution is indeed to-the-millisecond, but note that that may not be true for all browsers; [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666396/time-in-mouse-velocity-tracker/37666481?noredirect=1#comment62820365_37666481) that some browsers have resolution as low as 15ms while others may be in the 3-4ms range. In my tests, Chrome 50, Firefox 46, and IE11 all provide to-the-millisecond resolution; IE8 only manages about 10ms resolution.
2. If you only need to support fairly up-to-date browsers, you can use `performance.now()` ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#dom-performance-now) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)), which returns a [`DOMHighResTimeStamp`](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#idl-def-domhighrestimestamp) which is a floating-point number which:

   > ...SHOULD represent a time in milliseconds accurate to 5 microseconds...
   >
   > **NOTE**
   >
   > If the User Agent is unable to provide a time value accurate to 5 microseconds due to hardware or software constraints, the User Agent can represent a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` as a time in milliseconds accurate to a millisecond.

   So if the browser supports it, it is required to at *least* have millisecond resolution and ideally much, much better than that (via fractional values).

This snippet will test your current browser's `Date` object resolution ([here's an off-site version](http://output.jsbin.com/dapupiseto/1) that will work on older browsers like IE8):

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() {
      return new Date().getTime();
    };
  }

  var testcount = document.getElementById("testcount");
  var resolution = document.getElementById("resolution");

  document.getElementById("the-button").onclick = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var n = 0;

    log("Checking this browser's Date object resolution...");
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "";
    setTimeout(batch, 50);

    function batch() {
      var target = n + 1000;
      while (n < target) {
        sum += test();
        ++n;
      }
      testcount.innerHTML = n;
      resolution.innerHTML = (sum / n) + "ms";
      if (n < 10000) {
        setTimeout(batch, 50);
      } else {
        log("Done");
      }
    }
  };

  function test() {
    var x = Date.now();
    var y;
    do {
      y = Date.now();
    } while (x == y);
    return y - x;
  }

  function log(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="the-button" value="Test">
<div id="results" style="display: none">
  Tests so far: <span id="testcount">0</span>
  <br>Rough resolution: <span id="resolution"></span>
</div>
```

This snippet will test your current browser's `performance.now()` resolution, if it supports it:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  if (typeof performance !== "object" || !performance.now) {
    log("Your browser doesn't support performance.now()");
    return;
  }

  var testcount = document.getElementById("testcount");
  var resolution = document.getElementById("resolution");

  document.getElementById("the-button").onclick = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var n = 0;

    log("Checking this browser's performance.now() resolution...");
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "";
    setTimeout(batch, 50);

    function batch() {
      var target = n + 1000;
      while (n < target) {
        sum += test();
        ++n;
      }
      testcount.innerHTML = n;
      resolution.innerHTML = (sum / n) + "ms";
      if (n < 10000) {
        setTimeout(batch, 50);
      } else {
        log("Done");
      }
    }
  };

  function test() {
    var x = performance.now();
    var y;
    do {
      y = performance.now();
    } while (x == y);
    return y - x;
  }

  function log(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="the-button" value="Test">
<div id="results" style="display: none">
  Tests so far: <span id="testcount">0</span>
  <br>Rough resolution: <span id="resolution"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much:):):)

Comment: @Fistright—note that some browsers only have a resolution of around 15ms, and others perhaps 3 or 4ms so just because the value is milliseconds doesn't mean it's accurate to ­±1ms.

Comment: @RobG: Good point, I tend to forget that. I've added it above and mentioned the glaringly-missing `performance.now()`. :-)

Comment: Ok,my question now is another:if I move mouse for 1 px in minus than 1 millisecond what will be the velocity?

Comment: @Fistright: Velocity = distance / time, so 1px in 1ms is 1px/ms.

Comment: But in this case ms is 0...So the result will be 1px in 0 milliseconds?

Comment: @Fistright: You can't measure velocity over a time unit of zero, the number is meaningless.

Comment: Ok but in a condition like this what the function will return?

Comment: @Fistright: Again, you can't measure velocity over a time unit of zero. So do whatever you think best.

Comment: In your function how do you handle this case?

Comment: @Fistright: I don't have any functions for measuring mouse velocity. If you mean the examples above, look closely: It can never occur, because I wait until I see a change in the values and thus always have a value > 0.

Comment: Ok,thanks:):)In that function I don't see the onmousemove event so I don't understand after what event you catch mouse position and time.Excuse me for all these questions but I am new in javascript

Comment: @Fistright: I'm not. The question was *"...what Is the best time we can get?"* The answer addresses that: The best time measurements you can get are from `performance.now()` on browsers that support it, or from `Date.now()` on ones that don't. The code above demonstrates using them, and helps determine their resolution. Nothing to do with mouse velocity.